# Merging two JSON values as one to array

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object like

```
{
"key1" : "value1",
"key2" : "value2",
}
```

i need to convert this value as Javascript array by combining both the values like

```
var my_array = ["value1 value2"]; //value 1 and value 2 of JSON
```

I tried:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(countrylist);
var countries = [obj.value1+ " " + obj.value2];
```

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check it.

Comment: This is a typo. To access `value1` from obj, you have to use `obj.key1`

Comment: Note that there are no such things as a *JSON object*. JSONs are strings

Comment: just try this(if countrylist is a string and if first line given below exectues successfully you will get the output)
var obj = JSON.parse(countrylist);
var countries = [obj.key1+ " " + obj.key2];

Answer (score 2):

You can try this,

```
var obj = JSON.parse(countrylist);
var countries=Object.values(countrylist);
```

Here `Object` is a builtin javascript object.

To get the keys you can use `Object.keys(your_object)`